# How to do multiple math questions at once

Tags: javascript

I've tried a lot of things but it can only do 1+1 or 1-1 etc.

This is my code any fix or code to make this happen? thanks.

This uses the split method so you input has to be 1+1 etc

```
var Equation = prompt("Equation? (Can only take 1 math equation for now.      Upcoming updates soon!)");
  if (Equation === null) {
    close();
  }
  if (Equation.includes("+") === true) {
    const mySumAddition = Equation.split("+").map(x => parseFloat(x, 10));
    var AOne = mySumAddition[0], ATwo = mySumAddition[1];
    var additionAwnser = AOne + ATwo;
    alert(additionAwnser);
    var CO = confirm("Equation Done, Goodbye!");
  }
  if (Equation.includes("-") === true) {
    const mySumSubtraction = Equation.split("-").map(x => parseFloat(x,         10));
    var SOne = mySumSubtraction[0], STwo = mySumSubtraction[1];
    var subtractionAwnser = SOne - STwo;
    alert(subtractionAwnser);
    var CO = confirm("Equation Done, Goodbye!");
  }
  if (Equation.includes("*") === true) {
    const mySumMultiply = Equation.split("*").map(x => parseFloat(x, 10));
    var MOne = mySumMultiply[0], MTwo = mySumMultiply[1];
    var multiplyAwnser = MOne * MTwo;
    alert(multiplyAwnser)
    var CO = confirm("Equation Done, Goodbye!");
  }
  if (Equation.includes("/") === true) {
    const mySumDevision = Equation.split("/").map(x => parseFloat(x, 10));
    var DOne = mySumDevision[0], DTwo = mySumDevision[1];
    var devisionAwnser = DOne / DTwo;
    alert(devisionAwnser);
    var CO = confirm("Equation Done, Goodbye!");
  }
  if (CO === true) {
    close();
  }
  if (CO === false) {
    close();
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you need

Comment: Do you want to build a calculator?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the desired result? What is happening when you try doing multiple "Math questions"? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If what you want is to do multiple math questions at once like this `5+6+7+8-6-1*5+1`=`16` , `5+6+7+8-6-1*(5+1)`=`14` , `5**5`=`3125` (Equal to `5*5*5*5*5`=`3125`)then this code may work.

Note: Sorry if you don't understand what i say . i am not good English.

**Using *eval()* is high risk but *light code*** so add `if (!(/[a-z]/i.test(Equation))` to remove Equation that contain other code (eg. 1+'alert("You get infect")'+5) and only accept only number without other word (eg. 1+5+9*8/5-9)

```js
var Equation = prompt("Equation? (Can only take 1 math equation for now.      Upcoming updates soon!)");

if (Equation === null) close();
if (!(/[a-z]/i.test(Equation)) && Equation.match(/\+|\-|\/|\*/g)) {
  var Answer = eval(Equation);

  alert(Answer);
  console.log(Answer)
  var CO = confirm("Equation Done, Goodbye!");

} else {alert(`Equation contain other words`)}
if (CO === true) {
  close();
}
if (CO === false) {
  close();
}
```

This is a simple calculator

```js
var screen = document.querySelector(".screen > span");
document.querySelector(".equal-item").onclick = () => calc();
document.querySelector(".clear").onclick = () => screen.textContent = '';
document.querySelector(".back").onclick = () => screen.textContent = screen.textContent.substring(0, screen.textContent.length - 1);
document.querySelectorAll(".touche__box-item").forEach(a => a.onclick = () => screen.textContent += a.id)

const calc = () => {
  var Equation = screen.textContent;
  if (Equation === null) return;
  if (Equation.match(/\+|\-|\/|\*/g)) {
    var additionAwnser = eval(Equation);
    screen.textContent = additionAwnser;
  }
}
```

```css
.calculator {
  width: 408px;
  height: 837px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.screen-item {
  border-color: #f44336!important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #943797!important;
  letter-spacing: -0.1;
  background-color: rgb(0 150 0 / 6%)!important;
  position: absolute;
  width: 352px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  background: #ff7f24;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  top: 0px;
  left: 28px;
  text-align: right;
}

.screen-item span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.touche__box {
  position: relative;
  top: 91px;
  left: 27px;
}

.touche__box span {
  user-select: none;
  border-color: #f44336!important;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #943797!important;
  letter-spacing: -0.1;
  background-color: rgb(0 150 0 / 6%)!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 29px;
  line-height: 2.1;
}

.touche__box span:active {
  background-color: rgb(0 150 0 / 10%)!important;
}

.touche__box span.soustraction {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.touche__box .touche__box-item {
  width: 85px;
  height: 96px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ff2424;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
}

.touche__box .clear-item {
  width: 83px;
  height: 95px;
  background-color: #b421ea29;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
}

.touche__box .clear-item span {
  text-indent: 35px;
  line-height: 1.99;
}

.touche__box .zero-item {
  width: 174px;
  height: 96px;
}

.touche__box .zero-item span {
  text-indent: 79px;
}

.touche__box .zero-item,
.touche__box .un-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -97px;
}

.touche__box .equal-item {
  width: 85px;
  height: 96px;
  background-color: #b421ea29;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 194px;
}

.touche__box .equal-item span {
  line-height: 4;
}

.touche__box .clearme {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <main>

    <div class="container calculator">
      <div class="screen-item screen"> <span></span></div>
      <dl class="touche__box">
        <dt class="clear-item clear"> <span>C</span></dt><dt class="clear-item back"> <span>&lt;</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="-"> <span class="soustraction">_</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="+"><span class="sign">+</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item clearme" id="7"> <span>7</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="8"> <span>8</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="9"> <span>9</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="/"><span class="sign">/</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="4"> <span>4</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="5"> <span>5</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="6"> <span>6</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="*"><span class="sign">x</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="1"> <span>1</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="2"> <span>2</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item" id="3"> <span>3</span></dt>
        <dt class="equal-item" id="="><span class="sign-equal">=</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item zero-item" id="0"> <span>0</span></dt>
        <dt class="touche__box-item un-item" id="."><span class="sign">.</span></dt>
      </dl>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes thank you!! I have much respect for you.

Answer (score -1):

- In this code handle one question at a time. and closes once that equation has been processed. split the input into an array

  const equationArray = Equations.split(',');
- The input must be divided up into an array of equations. iterate the
  each equation in array using loop
  for(const Equation of equationArray) {
  // include your code inside loop
  }
- Don't equal into true in side the if condition, because if condition return true.